# Get the text from the field but if blank do this

Tags: java, if-statement, equals, jtextfield, gettext

I have a number of fields where data needs to be input. This is a Hotel Reservation system so if the fields arent filled it must display that they are empty and cannot proceed without filling them. What I want to do is get the text from the fields but if they are blank it must either set all the fields text to something like "*Please fill in all fields" or show up a message. 
I have some code which is not working because it cant get the text if there's nothing in the fields. The code looks like this:

```
    this.Firstname = NameF.getText();
        this.Lastname = NameL.getText();
        this.Country = Countr.getText();
        this.IDtype = IDTy.getText();
        this.PassportNo = PassNo.getText();
        this.IDNo = IDNumber.getText();
        this.Addr1 = Add1.getText();
        this.Addr2 = Add2.getText();
        this.AreaCode = Integer.parseInt(Area.getText());
        this.TelNo = Tel.getText();
        this.CellNo = Cell.getText();
        this.Email = Em.getText();
    }
    if (this.Firstname.equals("") || this.Lastname.equals("") || this.Country.equals("") || this.IDtype.equals("") || this.IDNo.equals("") || this.Addr1.equals("") || this.Addr2.equals("") || this.AreaCode == 0 || this.TelNo.equals("") || this.CellNo.equals("") || this.Email.equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill in all fields");
    }
```

Not sure if I should ask this in another question but is there an easier way to make the if without so many `||` operators?  Just like `if this.Firstname,this.Lastname,etc.equals("")`

Comment: Consider using JGoodies which help you to validate forms.

Comment: you may consider do validation when an `EventListener` happen, also you can ask for yourContainer.getComponents() and if component instanceof textfield validate there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by creating a function to do the checks for you in a loop;

```
public boolean isAnyEmpty(String... strArr){
    for(String s : strArr){
        if(s.equals("")) return true;
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Then call it with

```
if(isAnyEmpty(this.Firstname, this.lastName, this.Country, /* rest of your strings */)){
    //your code
}
```

This method makes use of [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) to let you treat the parameters as an array, without having to add in the additional code to  explicitly create one.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this.

```
public void validateFields () {
   for (String field : getNonBlankFields()) {
       if (field.equals("")) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill in all fields");
           return;
       }
   }
}

Collection<String> nonBlankFields;
public Collection<String> getNonBlankFields () {
    if (this.nonBlankFields != null) {
       return this.nonBlankFields;
    }
    this.nonBlankFields = new ArrayList<String> ();
    this.nonBlankFields.add(this.lastName);
    // add all of the other fields
    this.nonBlankFields.add(this.email);
    return this.nonBlankFields;
}
```

Comment: Even if you use map<"FirstName",this.firstName>, can show "Please fill First Name"...

Comment: When I fill in the fields it still shows the message to fill in all the fields. I realise that it hasn't 'gotten' the text and recognised what is in the fields because if that happens and nothing is found in all the fields it gives me a huge error

Comment: Try taking:

if (this.nonBlankFields != null) {
  return this.nonBlankFields;
}

out

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that will validate your `String`s in varargs flavor:

```
public boolean validateString(String ... stringsToValidate) {
    for (String validString : stringsToValidate) {
        if (...) { //logic to validate your String: not empty, not null, etc
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then just call it like this:

```
//add all the strings that must be validated with rules defined in validateString
if (!validateString(NameF.getText(), NameL.getText(), Countr.getText(), ...) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill in all fields");
}
```